# Can I directly connect to file on sharepoint without access to sharepoint main site?

Tags: python, sharepoint, databricks, shareplum

I have following issue.
I would like to get a content of csv file that is located in Sharepoint folder but each time I'm executing python code that uses Shareplum to refer to this Sharepoint folder, it throws

*ShareplumRequestError: Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://...

To better explain using below link I don't have access to ContosoSite but I have to the part that is after ContosoSite.

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ContosoSite/...

I believe that it is caused by lack of access to main site of Sharepoint which is ContosoSite.
I've tried the same thing but with Sharepoints to which I have the access to main site and it works fine.
The question is if I can do it somehow without access to main site?
Corporate regulations don't allow me to see content of main site but I can have access to folder that it contains.

Does anyone encounter such problem?
Best Regards

Comment: that link does not work FYI.  please update it.

Comment: It is just an example that show structure of Sharepoint site and to which part I refer.

Comment: without seeing this, it will be difficult for users here to help you.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can not provide real sharepoint site because it is managed by my company. Furthermore, I'm 99% sure that reason of this issue is lack of access to main Sharepoint site but what I'm asking is if there is any workaround for this.

Comment: if the break is lack of access, then you need to request permission and this is an invalid question for stack.

Comment: Well I'm aware that one of solution for lack of access is a request for that access but for this specific case I can't have such general access to this sharepoint. What I'm asking is if I can somehow query particular folder in this sharepoint to which I have access without general access. For instance, I can do it using Sharepoint connector in Azure Logic Apps and it works for this case but I would rather use python notebook on databricks. Is your real purpose to try to convience my that my post should be deleted?